Filtering does not work in the endpoint /alertmanager/grafana/api/v2/alert
I've tried a variety of approaches to filtering data, but none have worked. All attempts to get an alert for a given field (alert_rule_uid) were unsuccessful. Sample data:
"startsAt": "2023-05-26T04:04:00.000+03:00",
"status": {
  "inhibitedBy": [],
  "silencedBy": [],
  "state": "active"
},
"updatedAt": "2024-10-21T17:12:40.692+03:00",
"generatorURL": "https://someurl/view",
"labels": {
  "__alert_rule_uid__": "yfluEK1217k",
  "alertname": "DatasourceError",
  "grafana_folder": "DevOps",
  "rule_uid": "yfluEK17k",
  "rulename": "CPU usage % u-c2 alert"
}
}
{
"annotations": {
  "__alertId__": "10007",
  "__dashboardUid__": "Enr22aSuGk",
  "__orgId__": "1",
  "__panelId__": "150"
},
"endsAt": "2024-10-21T17:14:00.000+03:00",
"fingerprint": "f796f60b324752bc0",
"receivers": [
  {
    "active": null,
    "integrations": null,
    "name": "grafana-default-email"
  }
],
"startsAt": "2024-09-11T07:24:00.000+03:00",
"status": {
  "inhibitedBy": [],
  "silencedBy": [],
  "state": "active"
},
"updatedAt": "2024-10-21T17:12:06.054+03:00",
"generatorURL": "https://someurl/view",
"labels": {
  "__alert_rule_uid__": "FEj22XEKJ7k",
  "alertname": "DatasourceError",
  "datasource_uid": "ZOJqa222IGz",
  "grafana_folder": "somefolder",
  "ref_id": "F",
  "rule_uid": "FEjXEKJ7k",
  "rulename": "POD not running alert"
}
}
{
"annotations": {
  "__alertId__": "327",
  "__dashboardUid__": "mkD9f2wMz",
  "__orgId__": "1",
  "__panelId__": "6",
  "description": "Load Average 15m 1 more than \"1\""
},
"endsAt": "2024-10-21T17:16:00.000+03:00",
"fingerprint": "f9fa7a8b3c1219bedf",
"receivers": [
  {
    "active": null,
    "integrations": null,
    "name": "grafana-default-email"
  }
],

A few examples of how I requested data:
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://raw.githubusercontent.com/api/alertmanager/grafana/api/v2/alerts?active=true&silenced=true&inhibited=true&filter=yfluEK1217k' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'

curl -X 'GET' \
'localhost:3000/api/alertmanager/grafana/api/v2/alerts?active=true&silenced=true&inhibited=true&filter=rule_uid%5BtD_XPKJnk%5D'\
  -H 'accept: application/json'

curl 'localhost:3000/api/alertmanager/grafana/api/v2/alerts?active=true&silenced=true&inhibited=true&filter=fingerprint=01ca1c11539cde25' \
 -X GET \
 -H "Accept: application/json"\

It can be reproduced as follows:

Add alert rules
Write a request to receive alerts with filter
Try to execute it and get an alert for a unique value

Grafana v10.4.3
